# Detect PCI vs. PCI-E

Tags: linux, pci-express, pci, expansion-cards

I have remote access to a computer, and I need to find out what kind of expansion slots is has, if they are PCI, or PCI-E, or something else. How can I do this from a shell? What commands are there that would report the type and number of expansion slots?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`dmidecode` should display the information regarding the slots on your system.

The command needs to be run as root.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try `lspci -vvv`, but I'm not sure if it will work with a remote machine.